# Mysql regex to exclude non-word character

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql 5.6. I am trying a query where I have to pick up only those rows that do not have any non-word character ( like =, %, space, tab etc) and have only characters and numbers.

So tried:

```
SELECT username 
   FROM users
   WHERE username REGEXP '.*[a-zA-Z0-9].*$' 
   and username NOT REGEXP '%=\t\s@?,:'
```

and I am getting the error: syntax error in line 3 and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT username 
  FROM users
 WHERE username REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
```

or alternatively

```
SELECT username 
  FROM users
 WHERE username REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=eeb302a705bb4fe7cf5795adef5fb420)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

One method is:

```
WHERE NOT username REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```